# Creating and Validating Transactions through a VB.NET program

Tags: vb.net, validation, transactions

I would like some pointers about how to go with the following scenario:
I am developing a simple app to be used as a secondary app in a bank and I would like it to have the user enter a transaction (let say an outward remittance) and then the bank manager validates the transaction before actually it is processed through the clearing system.
The way I did it in the previous version was to actually insert the transaction as a row in the database with the userID and the creation date. (with a binary flag as not valid).
then when the manager validates the transaction, it is updated with his Id, the validation date and the flag is set to "Valid". the transaction is then processed through clearing.
I dont know if there is a more "elegant" way to do it. A pointer to a tutorial would highly be appreciated.
the application is developed with VB 2010 and Sql Server 2012.
Many thanks,

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you need a way to store input entries and query/update them later, a perfect candidate for a database IMO. There may be more elegant database structures, but as a general approach yours seems sensible. Did you find any limitations with your approach before? If not, what makes you question its validity?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is valid and this kind of solution is widely used.

There are obviously many things to consider that we can't do for you without the knowledge of your system but in principle this is a good solution.

Some points to consider:

- concurrency in accessing the transactions (many managers?)
- creating/approving multiple records in a transaction? Or one by one?
- auditing (making sure you capture all information needed for audits)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Actually the way I'm handling this is working as there are at most three users and at most two managers.
I am lacking the concurrency management and the audit.
when a manager points at a transaction it is displayed to him in the following steps:
a datatablerow is filled with the transaction details which are displayed to the manager to make decision. If he agrees on the content, and update transaction to "Valid" is done upon click on valid button
this makes the transaction vulnerable to be changed by the user after the display to the manager, hence validading

Comment: an undisplayed content.
the Display is done through datatablerow = ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE CODE='" & sCODE & "' AND NBR='" & sNBR & "'")) each field in the row is then displayed in a given control (texbox, cmbbox or lbl).
the update is done through the following statement ExecQuery(UPDATE TBL  SET [ST_VALID] ='True' , [UTLVAL] = '" & USERNAME & "' , [DATE_VALID] = GETDATE() , [UTLUPDATE] = '" & USERNAME & "' , [LAST_UPDATE]= GETDATE() WHERE  [ST_COMPTA] ='False' AND  CODE+NBR='" & REF & "').
I should lock the row while it is being displayed to manager to make sure that no

Comment: modification is done to the displayed row. I just dont know how to do it. I'd also love to have some pointers as to how to have an audit trail in the system.
Any directions on these issues will be highly appreciated